# How can I highlight UIInput using Primefaces when validation upon ajax request fails?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

Validator Class:

```
@FacesValidator("br.gov.valec.sicpd.util.CpfValidator")
public class CpfValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException {
        if (validateCpf(value.toString())) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Invalid Input","Invalid Input");
            ((UIInput) component).setValid(false); // this line doesnt work

        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
    }
}
```

JSF snippet:

```
<p:inputText label="CPF" id="inputCpf"
                    value="#{mainBean.owner.cpf}">
                    <f:validator validatorId="br.gov.valec.sicpd.util.CpfValidator" />
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="inputNameOwner"
                        listener="#{mainBean.searchOwner}"  />
</p:inputText>
```

When the form is submitted via command button primefaces highlights it automatically. How can I achieve that when ajax is fired and validation fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UIInput#setValid(false)` is working fine. You just forgot to tell ajax to update the input component itself. Add `inputCpf` or `@this` to `<p:ajax update>`.

```
<p:ajax ... update="@this inputNameOwner" />
```

That explicit `UIInput#setValid(false)` call in validator is by the way unnecessary. Get rid of it. JSF already does it all by itself once it catches the `ValidatorException` thrown by your validator.