# Validate data if the value empty or 0

Tags: validation, jsf

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<p:outputLabel for="Adjamount" value="Adj Amount" />
    <t:div id = "tax6">
        <p:inputText size="15" id="Adjamount" value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.selectedData.adjstAmount}" required= "true">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###,##0.00"/>
        </p:inputText>
    </t:div>
```

[image]

How do I make the `0.00` in Adj Amount highlighted just like Product Adjustment when the value is `empty` or `0.00`?
I already know what to do when the value is empty "just input `required='true'`". I only want to know how do I validate and inform user what happen if he/she insert 0.

Comment: Please upload image with question not outside the Stackoverflow.

Comment: Here are some link which can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474140/how-can-i-highlight-uiinput-using-primefaces-when-validation-upon-ajax-request-f OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376875/jsf2-primefaces-how-to-highlight-the-inputtext-border-with-red-color

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: people with little reputation can't upload images in stackoverflow